# Markov Chain: reusable R function to display state values in n timesteps?

Tags: r, function, arguments, parameter-passing, markov-chains

**I have this simple Markov Chain:**

```
library(markovchain)
mcSIR <- new("markovchain", states=c("S","I","R"),
    transitionMatrix=matrix(data=c(0.9,0.1,0,0,0.8,0.2,0,0,1),
    byrow=TRUE, nrow=3), name="SIR")
is <- c(99,1,0) # initial States
```

How do I define a *reusable* function "**fvals**",
which returns (for *any* Markov Chain),
a Data Frame with the state values for n timesteps?

**The call would be like this:**

```
   fvals(mcSIR,is,5) # show state values for 5 timesteps
```

**The Data Frame output of "fvals" 
would look like this:**
(*note*: timesteps are the 2nd col from left and start at zero).

```
1    timestep            S            I            R
2           0           99            1            0
3           1         89.1         10.7          0.2
4           2        80.19        17.47         2.34
5           3        72.17           22         5.83
6           4        64.95        24.81        10.23
7           5        58.46        26.35         15.2
```

**Reason:** This function would be useful to test different MCs,
without repeating the R code for each one, each time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function could help you:

```
fvals<-function(mchain,initialstate,n) {
  names(initialstate)<-names(mchain)
  for (i in 0:n)
  {
    out<-initialstate*mchain^(i)
    cat(i," ",out,"\n")
  }
}
fvals(mcSIR,is,5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple and effective answer, Giorgio! It works.    Q1) How to convert the output of fvals() to a "regular" data frame?.      
  Q2)  Maybe this useful and frequently used function (fvals)
could be incorporated into the "markovchain" package?

Comment: Hi, this might helps: https://qualityandinnovation.com/2015/12/08/a-discrete-time-markov-chain-dtmc-sir-model-in-r/